# NodeMCU hostname is not visible on Home Router

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

NodeMCU 
Lua : 5.1.4 on SDK 1.5.4.1

Problem : 
I use code below, and on my home routers (Huawei and LG) there is no NodeMCU listed on connected devices.
IPAddress from DHCP is correct. I can ping to NodeMCU from other PC in the same network but its not showing on Routers Connected Devices list.

```
-----------------------------------------------
--- Set Variables ---
-----------------------------------------------
--- WIFI CONFIGURATION ---
WIFI_SSID = "ssidname"
WIFI_PASSWORD = "passwd"
--WIFI_SIGNAL_MODE = wifi.PHYMODE_N

--- IP CONFIG (Leave blank to use DHCP) ---
ESP8266_IP="0.0.0.0"
ESP8266_NETMASK="0.0.0.0"
ESP8266_GATEWAY="0.0.0.0"
-----------------------------------------------

--- Connect to the wifi network ---
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION) 
wifi.sta.setmac(wifi.sta.getmac())
wifi.sta.config(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD, 1) 
wifi.sta.sethostname("MYNODE")
--if ESP8266_IP ~= "" then
-- wifi.sta.setip({ip=ESP8266_IP,netmask=ESP8266_NETMASK,gateway=ESP8266_GATEWAY})
--end
-----------------------------------------------

--- Check the IP Address ---
print(wifi.sta.getip())
print(wifi.sta.gethostname())
```

Comment: I use the Arduino firmware, not Lua, but in that I tend to use `MDNS.begin("hostname")`.  I have several, and they show up on the network and can be accessed by name rather than IP address.  [Here is the Lua MDNS](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/mdns/) information.